# Sharepoint site running in a VM

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Basic question...I have a site running in a VM, say the URL is http://localhost/sites/foo/default.aspx
I want to surf to the URL from my host box, so I get the IP of the VM, and I try:
http:///sites/foo/default.aspx.
When I do, I get an error:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Shouldn't I be able to do this, isn't this basic?
I also tried using the IP on in a browser on the VM (instead of localhost), but I get the same error.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message means that IIS would like to display a .NET error to you, but your web.config file is not set up to allow that.

I'm not sure where the web.config file is located for sharepoint, but when you find it, you can change it to this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

That way, you'll be able to see the error message remotely.

Comment: Thanks...do I need to restart each time I touch web.config?

Comment: Nope, the restart happens automatically when you edit the file (as long as you have the correct filesystem permissions to edit it).

Answer (score 1):

You must to place that VM IP into your `hosts` file and to associate it with your Sharepoint real website (i.e., *not* localhost)